# When are existential quantifiers in the intuitionistic propositional calculus eliminable and when not

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, propositional-logic

I am so ignorant I don't even know where should I ask this - on FOM? On mathoverflow? On cstheory? So please consider as sort of a meta-question readdressing me in case you think this is a wrong site. (Also my tags are most probably wrong, sorry)

The simple case when I definitely know the answer and it is positive: given some propositional formula $\phi$, I know that there is an $x$ such that $\phi$ is IPC-equivalent to $x\lor\neg x$ if and only if $\neg\phi$ is equivalent to $\bot$.

Two simplest cases when I suspect the answer is negative but I don't know how to prove it: again given some $\phi$, when does there exist an $x$ such that $\phi$ is IPC-equivalent to $\neg x\lor\neg\neg x$; or when does there exist an $x$ such that $\neg x$ is equivalent to $\bot$ and $\phi$ is equivalent to $x\lor\neg x$. In these two cases I can formulate necessary first order conditions on $\mathscr V(\phi)$ in any valuation $\mathscr V$ under either Kripke or some more general semantics, but I suspect that I cannot eliminate existential quantifier staying in IPC.

How to approach such questions? What science is this? Is there some software which I can use for MUCH more complicated expressions?

Comment: math.stackexchange.com ან mathoverflow.net ჯობია, სავარაუდოდ.

Comment: @zkutch მადლობა, ზურა, ვცდი მანდაც, ოღონდ ცოტას შევიცლი, იქნებ ვინმემ რამე მოიწეროს :)

Comment: This, as it stands, is definitely a question for [math.SE], once you've worded it as a question rather than a meta-question. If you're asking a question about intuitionistic logic, then this is a mathematical question. But if your question touches on (say) lambda calculus and type theory, then that would be appropriate here. In future, if you're unsure, we do have a place for meta-questions: [meta.cs.SE].

Comment: A better question for Mathematics as pointed out already. For software capable of propositional logic, Isabelle is nice. https://isabelle.in.tum.de/